# How to connect different deployments in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have two back-end deployments, REST server and a database server, each running on some specific ports. The REST server internally calls a database server.

Now how do I refer my database server deployment in my REST server deployment so that they can communicate with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, define a service for your DB server, that will create sort of a loadbalancer (internal kube integration based on iptables in most cases). With that, you will be able to refer to it by service name or fqdn like `mydbsvc.namespace.svc.cluster.local`. Which will return "Cluster IP" to that loadbalancer.

Then it's just an issue of regular app config to point it to your DB on `mydbsvc`, preferably by means of env variable like say DB_HOST=mydbsvc set in your REST API deployment manifest (pod template envs)

Comment: @radek-goblin-pieczonka I had used `db-svc` as the service name of my DB. But when I tried to connect to it, it said `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:db-svc`

Comment: the driver thing is unrelated to kubernetes at all. this needs to be supported on your image level

Comment: Yeah I get that but the deployment should have resolved the DB service name as you said right? Oram I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Expose your deployments as service. For example, kubectl expose ...
2. Connect/Allow these to communicate by creating network policies.

Service object (of database) will give you a virtual (stable) IP. Depending upon the type of service your rest code can call DB via clusterIP/externalName/externalIP/DNS.